# Точка с запятой в конце элемента списка при союзе "или"

Tags: пунктуация, список, точка-с-запятой

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать со знаками препинания, если в тексте такой список:

*Выбор ваш невелик:


- вы открываете магазин и начинаете работать в нём или(;)


- сидите дома и ничего не делаете.*

Нужна ли точка с запятой после первого элемента списка? После союза "или" она смотрится не очень хорошо, но по правилам-то стоит там на месте. Спасибо!

Comment: Невеликий список — не список. У вас две позиции: нет причин такой формы.

Comment: @shampar Правильно: нет причин **для** такой формы.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна точка с запятой.

Но "или" нужно убрать. Его нельзя ставить между элементами списка. Сам новый элемент уже подразумевает "или".

Примечание:

Элементы списка равносильны. Поэтому лучше использовать слово "вы" в каждом элементе или вообще его не использовать.

Так как список маленький, его можно оформить обычным предложением:

*Выбор ваш невелик: вы открываете магазин и начинаете работать в нем или сидите дома и ничего не делаете.*

Comment: Новый элемент может подразумевать «и».

Answer (score -2):

Вы знаете, это вопрос не по русскому языку, а по верстке текста.
Но если с позиций именно языковых, то такое оформление списка не приветствуется. 
Если вы делаете список, то в нем уже не должно быть никаких или. Если уж совсем невмоготу - перенесите его на следующую строчку, тогда никакого знака и не понадобится.

Ну вот как-то так

Выбор ваш невелик:
- вы открываете магазин и начинаете работать в нем
- или сидите дома и ничего не делаете.

Выбор ваш невелик:
- вы открываете магазин и начинаете работать в нем;
- сидите дома и ничего не делаете.

И самое главное. Этот пример совершенно умозрителен. Такие вещи списком оформляют разве что для ознакомительного примера работы типографской программы.

Comment: Есть у вас примеры списков без знаков в конце пункта? И с чего вы взяли, что один элемент может начинаться с "или"?

Comment: @oleedd Что именно запрещает новому элементу начинаться с «или»?